# O que há de novo entre o HTML5.2 e o HTML5?

Tags: html, html5

Segundo o Wikipedia no [tópico HTML](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML), observa-se a seguinte tabela de versões do HTML e o seus respectivos anos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Entrando no [tópico HTML5](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5) no mesmo site, apenas diz que:

> Esta nova versão traz consigo importantes mudanças quanto ao papel do
>   HTML no mundo da Web, através de novas funcionalidades como semântica
>   e acessibilidade. Possibilita o uso de novos recursos antes possíveis
>   apenas com a aplicação de outras tecnologias. Sua essência tem sido
>   melhorar a linguagem com o suporte para as mais recentes multimídias,
>   enquanto a mantém facilmente legível por seres humanos e
>   consistentemente compreendida por computadores e outros dispositivos
>   (navegadores, parsers etc).

Ou seja, é uma descrição genérica da versão 5 do HTML, mas não encontrei nada a respeito de subdivisões da versão (5.1 e 5.2).

Minha dúvida é — deixando de lado a versão 5.1 —, o que a versão 5.2 traz de novo em relação à versão 5 inicial do HTML?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A lista das mudança do HTML `5.1` paro o `5.2` é um pouco extensa, porém é documentada, inclusive mostrando a compatibilidade entre os browsers para cada nova implementação. Vc pode consultar a lista completa aqui: https://w3c.github.io/test-results/html52/implementation-report.html

A Lista é dividia em 3 partes. **Recursos Alterados**, **Recursos Removidos** e **Recursos em Implementação**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***Essa é só uma parde das Mudanças Documentadas, Consultar o resto no link:*** https://w3c.github.io/test-results/html52/implementation-report.html

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

### Novidades interessantes do HTML 5.2

- **Uma nova forma de fazer modais:** De todas as novidades implementadas com a nova versão do HTML, a introdução do elemento `<dialog>` é de longe a mais interessante.

  `<dialog>
       <h2>Cabeçalho do modal</h2>
       <p>Conteúdo do modal, podendo incluir texto, imagens, links, vídeos etc.</p>
  </dialog>`
- **Múltiplos elementos principais:** Anteriormente, cada página web só poderia conter um elemento `<main>` ou seria considerada inválida.
- APIs de pagamentos em `iframes`
- **Estilos no corpo da página:** Embora definições de estilo sejam normalmente inseridas no  dos documentos, a partir do HTML 5.2 se torna válido definir estilos dentro do elemento `<body>` também, embora a própria W3C não recomende a prática.

  `<body>
      <p class="azul">Texto azul!</p>
      <style>
          .azul { color: #0000FF; }
      </style>
  </body>`
- **Cabeçalhos em legendas:** A partir do HTML 5.2, é possível introduzir cabeçalhos (`<h1>` até `<h6>`) em elementos `<legend>` de formulários.
- **O que se torna obsoleto ou inválido com o HTML 5.2**

O elemento `<keygen>`, anteriormente utilizado para gerar chaves públicas em formulários foi removido das especificações.

Os elementos `<menu>` e `<menuitem>` também não fazem mais parte das especificações do HTML. Eles eram utilizados até então para a criação de menus de navegação ou contexto.

A partir de agora, o elemento `<p>` só pode conter elementos `inline` como filhos válidos. Ou seja, elementos dos tipos `inline-block`, `inline-table` ou `block` não podem mais serem aninhados dentro de um elemento `<p>` de forma semanticamente válida.

---

> **Saíram do HTML 5.2**

Os elementos `<keygen>`, `<menu>` e `<menuitem>`.
Atributo inputmode para elementos `<text>` e os atributos de `dropzone`.
Método `showModalDialog`.
A **Plugin API** foi marcada como **obsoleta**.

> **As seguintes construções agora são válidas no HTML 5.2:**

Utilização do elemento `<style>` dentro do elemento `<body>`.
Múltiplos elementos `<main>` no `DOM`, desde que apenas um seja visível para o usuário.
Possibilidade de ter um elemento `<div>` como filho de um elemento `<dl>`.
Cabeçalhos dentro de um elemento `<legend>` em um `<fieldset`>.

***Fonte 1:*** https://imasters.com.br/desenvolvimento/html-5-2-o-que-nova-recomendacao-do-w3c-traz-de-novidade-para-o-desenvolvimento-web

***Fonte 2:*** https://www.codigofonte.com.br/artigos/conheca-o-html-5-2

---

**Versão 5.1:** Essa é a lista das implementações do `HTML 5.1` https://w3c.github.io/test-results/html51/implementation-report.html

**Versão 5.3 *Draft*:** Lista dos drafts do `HTML 5.3` https://www.w3.org/TR/html53/